# Step for step how to embed Mapquest into Flash using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dictionary, embed

2 links that might help. I am new to Flash and have no idea what to do. Will it take me longer than a couple hours to complete this?

http://developer.mapquest.com/en_GB/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash

http://developer.mapquest.com/en_GB/web/products/open/flash

I worked out how to get an API Key, so I have one now.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least a basic understanding of programming and object orientated design before attempting to tackle something like this. Even if you do, Flash has it's own specific way of handling graphical objects, so it might be a good idea to get comfortable with AS3 before trying to tackle 3rd party libraries.

That said, there's a fairly straightforward example right in the documentation:

[Maps > AS3 Map](http://developer.mapquest.com/content/as/v/mq/samples/samplesexplorer/index.html)

However, if you're looking to add in your own custom functionality, or more of the libraries' classes, I'd strongly advise getting a solid foundation in AS3 first.